# Find PHP microtime 1 day ago

Tags: php, date, datetime, microtime

How to find 1 day ago time in PHP `microtime()` format.

I am trying like this. But still showing the current time.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-1 day'));
$val = microtime($date);
```

Comment: `var_dump(strtotime('-1 day'));`

Comment: @u_mulder I corrected my answer according to this, thank you.

Comment: @Naren if my answer helped you please mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

> microtime() returns the current Unix timestamp with microseconds

You can't use microtime() to get a time from the past, since the funtion only works with current date.

Wouldn't this work for you?

```
$date = strtotime('-1 day');
```

Edit: Code corrected according to u_mulder's comment.

Comment: @u_mulder yeah I realized as soon as I read your comment on the question, I didn't realize it at first :D Thank you for noticing ;)